# Please give a Name to this lemma

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm reading a .pdf file about Probability. [Here's](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Krokhmal.pdf) the link

The author introduces the **lemma 4.1**, suggesting to consult the proof in a specific book. I tried to search the lemma in the book but i didn't find it. Please help me to find a name for this lemma so as i can consult its proof...

> **Lemma 4.1.** Let $Z_1, Z_2, \dots$ be a sequence of random variables having distribution functions $F_{Z_n}$ and moment generating functions $M_{Z_n}$ s.t. $n \geq 1$. Furthermore, let $Z$ be a random variable having distribution $F_Z$ and moment generating function $M_Z$. If $M_{Z_n}(t) \to M_Z$ for all $t$, then $F_{Z_n}(t) \to F_{Z}(t)$ for all $t$ at which $F_Z(t)$ is continuous.

Comment: If you won't take the trouble to retype the lemma, perhaps you could say what page it's on.

Comment: Could you give us **directly** the lemma (copy-paste it, for instance) instead of linking to a whole pdf?

Comment: picture of the lemma added in the main post

Comment: Most treatments of that proof are not appropriate for the level of probability expected that you've linked. You will need measure theory. See Arnaud's link.

Comment: This looks like the MGF version of [Levy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem). In any canse I'm not sure that this can be easily proven without using measure theory.